# Resolving an ambiguous column in a subselect

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery, left-join

I'm having trouble selecting a column from a subselect that has a shared name between two joined tables using the `ON` join expression syntax.

I have two tables, `event` and `geography` each of which has a `geography_id` column, which is the same data type, and `event.geography_id` is a foreign key into `geography` (geography provides information about an event):

[image: simplified ERD from Dia]

The problem I'm having is that I can't reference the shared column between these two tables when joining them using the `ON` syntax, but it works when using the `USING` syntax.

I realize that `USING` works because it [suppresses redundant columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/queries-table-expressions.html), but since the statement uses many different joined tables with schemas that change more often than not, I would rather be as explicit as possible.

The specific SQL I'm having trouble with is:

```
select
    x.event_id
from (
    select * from event e
    left join geography g on (e.geography_id = g.geography_id)
) x
where
    x.geography_id in (1,2,3)
```

Which gives the error:

> ERROR:  column reference "geography_id" is ambiguous
>
> LINE 8:     x.geography_id in (1,2,3)

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.0.14.

Comment: You need to list each column individually in the derived table (sub-select). That's the only alternative to the `using` clause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be a very helpful feature in SQL to be able to select all columns *except* one or more that you explicitly want to exclude. If it existed, you could have used such a feature to solve your problem by excluding `g.geography_id`. Unfortunately, such a feature does not appear to exist anywhere, in any DBMS. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/sql-select-all-columns-except-some.

One solution, as @a_horse_with_no_name commented, is to list every single column you want to select, and just omit the ones you don't.

There is actually another, probably preferable, solution, which is to select `*` and also `e.geography_id`, but alias the latter to another name that will then be unambiguous in the subquery result-set. Something like this:

```
select
    x.event_id
from (
    select *, e.geography_id geography_id1 from event e
    left join geography g on (e.geography_id = g.geography_id)
) x
where
    x.geography_id1 in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution, and the only one that doesn't involve restructuring the entire query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write the query as:

```
select
    e.event_id
from event e
    left join geography g 
      on (e.geography_id = g.geography_id)
where
    e.geography_id in (1,2,3)
```

That should be logically equivalent, or switch to:

```
where
    g.geography_id in (1,2,3)
```

to get returns that only have matches (which would beg the question why not use an inner join)

Comment: Can't use an inner join because the `geography_id` where clause is optional (if unspecified, returns all events regardless of whether they have a geography), and `x.geography_id is null` is also a possible clause.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the predicate down into a subquery *before* you join:

```
SELECT e.event_id
FROM  (SELECT * FROM event WHERE geography_id IN (1,2,3)) e
LEFT   JOIN geography g ON (g.geography_id = e.geography_id);
```

The result is 100 % equivalent to your original query:

```
SELECT e.event_id
FROM   event e
LEFT   JOIN geography g USING (geography_id)
WHERE  geography_id in (1,2,3);
```

Just that the alternative should be much faster (excludes irrelevant rows early). Quite an acceptable side effect for a workaround.